# Jenkins Windows Batch Command: How to pass non-Latin file path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, encoding

I faced a problem today with running a windows batch command with Jenkins (at the time of writing I have Jenkins v1.607).
I'm trying to create a job to convert a DOCX to PDF file with OfficeToPDF.
With Latin filenames all OK, but when pass the Cyrillic filename as parameter it simply says "Can not find file". I guess it's all about encoding.

**The workaround** is to use for input parameter a short 8.3 filename, and Latin transcription for output PDF file name.

*But how can I pass non-Latin file path correctly to allow the tool export to the Cyrillic file path?*

Comment: @ManoDestra thaks for the edit. Up to the moment of writing the question I had already spent 8 hours of trying to solve the problem .

Comment: Yeah! Take counsel of one's pillow. Really! 
Use "Inject environment variables to the build process" with necessary file names. In my case I set:
`SourceFileName=.\doc\Файл1.docx` and `ExportFileName=.\output\Файл1.pdf`, then I rewrote Windows Batch Command with `"%WORKSPACE%\OfficeToPDF\convert.cmd" "%SourceFileName%" "%ExportFileName%"`. This allows Jenkins to pass parameters in correct encoding.
But another problem is to Archive Artifacts, Jenkins won't archive artifacts correctly.

Comment: The problem with Archive Artifact related only to versions until 1.607.
Today I have upgraded Jenkins to 2.7 and now the problem is solved.